# Raspberry Pi automounts NAS on Airport Extreme

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, mount

So I'm new to linux.  I bought a raspberry pi that I want to mount my Apple Airport Extreme's HDD.  I was able to find this online:

```
sudo mount.cifs //10.0.1.1/Files /media/Files -o rw,user=pi,uid=pi,pass="password"
```

The above command mounts my Airport Extreme's HDD to the /media/Files mount point correctly.  But I have to enter this command everytime I restart my RPi.

How do I add this to my fstab so it will mount automatically when I boot up the raspberry pi?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Raspberry Pi. Question should be moved to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

As root, open the fstab file in your favorite editor

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

at the bottom, add

```
//10.0.1.1/Files  /media/Files  cifs  rw,user=pi,uid=pi,pass="password",auto  0  0
```

Please share how it worked out.